# JSON Post body not parsing as expected

Tags: python, json, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a python function hosted on aws that takes an event and then does a bunch of things, but essentially the problem lies at parsing the incoming POST request.

My code looks like this:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    merchantid = json.dumps(event['body'])
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(merchantid)
    }
```

To send the post request I am just using the aws API Gateway test that comes with the website, so it shouldn't be any weird encoding.

As I am passing in a JSON object, I expect the merchantid field to be storing a json object.

Instead, it returns this string:

```
"\"{\\n    \\\"merchantEmail\\\": \\\"timcook@gmail.com\\\",\\n    \\\"customerEmail\\\": \\\"billgates@gmail.com\\\",\\n    \\\"merchantWallet\\\": \\\"mWallet\\\",\\n    \\\"transactionTotal\\\": 1.00,\\n    \\\"transactionDenomination\\\": \\\"AUD\\\",\\n    \\\"customerCurrency\\\": \\\"EUR\\\",\\n    \\\"merchantAccess\\\" : {\\n        \\\"merchantKey\\\": \\\"key\\\",\\n        \\\"merchantSecret\\\": \\\"secret\\\"\\n    },\\n    \\\"customerAccess\\\" : {\\n        \\\"customerKey\\\": \\\"ckey\\\",\\n        \\\"customerSecret\\\": \\\"csecret\\\"\\n    }\\n}\""
```

I have never seen a string like this, and I can not seem to get this to return to JSON format.

Does anybody know how I can return this to the orignal JSON format that was submitted in the body?

I should mention that the lambda_handler works perfectly fine with the JSON using the test event, it was only once I started to try and trigger it with the API Gateway that I started having this problem.

edit:
This is the JSON object I am passing as the body of the PUT request:

```
{
    "merchantEmail": "timcook@gmail.com",
    "customerEmail": "billgates@gmail.com",
    "merchantWallet": "mWallet",
    "transactionTotal": 1.00,
    "transactionDenomination": "AUD",
    "customerCurrency": "EUR",
    "merchantAccess" : {
        "merchantKey": "key",
        "merchantSecret": "secret"
    },
    "customerAccess" : {
        "customerKey": "ckey",
        "customerSecret": "csecret"
    }
}
```

edit:
Before I attached the API Gateway I was handling it with

```
merchantid = event['merchantEmail']
```

but once I passed it in as the body of a PUT is would return a 502 internal server error

Comment: why do you need json.dumps ?

Comment: Could you please post the JSON object you put in so we can try to repeat what you've done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check this what is the datatype of the event params, Is it a string, or Is it dict.

if the datatype of body key value is `JSON (dict)`

`merchantid = event.get('body').get('merchantEmail')`

if the datatype of body key value is `String (str)`

`merchantid = json.loads(event.get('body')).get('merchantEmail')`

Comment: Thanks Mrinal, using loads worked for me, as it was being captured as a string. I'm a little bit confused why it's not being captured as a dict, even if I specify in the header `"Content-Type": "application/json"`. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Sorry Mrinal, if I do

`resp = json.loads(event.get('body'))
    print(resp)
    print(type(resp))`

then it prints as type dict.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Nested JSON Comes as String, even if you pass 'Content-Type" set as application/json

Answer (score 1):

The `event` argument that you get into the Lambda function is a python [dict](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html).

Assuming you know the dict structure - all you need to do is the read the value you are looking for.

Example:

`data = event['my_key']`

Comment: I think that's part of the problem if I try to access it like this  `merchantid = event['body']
    print(type(merchantid))` it prints <class 'str'> not <class 'dict'>